# Count the size of an array in another column?

Tags: sql-server

I'm trying to update "Count_Column" in "My_Table" to get the count of the array size in Array_Column

```
UPDATE TABLE [dbo1].[My_Table]
SET [Count_Column] as COUNT(Array_Column.test);
```

Array_Column in a column that has a JSON array in it

Comment: This doesn't make any sense. Can you share the table definition, some sample data and desired output?

Comment: Array_Column is a table?

Comment: Sorry, Array_Column in a column that has a JSON array in it

Comment: @Pythonaccount I don't think you can read JSON from a column. What's is the type of the column?

Comment: @Paul Sinnema It's nvarchar

Comment: You will have to do this in code. You could maybe able to create a stored procedure to do this but it would be ugly.

Comment: Ah, there are a JSON functions in SQL server you could use. Take a look here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/json/json-data-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver16

Comment: Honestly, a `VIEW` is the right call here in my opinion. Storing aggregated data in a table is almost always a mistake, as you either have to expect it to be wrong (because something has changed and the aggregate hasn't), or you have to have things like triggers to `UPDATE` the values **every** time there is an `INSERT`/`UPDATE`/`DELETE`. You can't create a computed column for this, as you'll need to use `OPENJSON` too. As such a `VIEW` is your best bet, as it'll always be correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's unclear why you want to store this information a second time, ideally you would just query it when needed.

Be that as it may, you need to break out the array using `OPENJSON`

```sql
UPDATE dbo1.My_Table
SET Count_Column = (
    SELECT COUNT(*)
    FROM OPENJSON(My_Table.Array_Column, '$.test')
);
```

This assumes that the array is located in a property called `test`, for example:

```json
{
  "test" : [
    1,
    2
  ]
}
```

would return `2`

Comment: Cool, learned something today ;-) I do agree with @Charlieface that you would be better of querying for the count each time you need it. The value in your column may get out of sync with the real number of entries in the JSON.